# accessing JSONB values using scalikejdbc-async

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.4, scalikejdbc

We are evaluating using scalikejdbc-async for a new play project. The new postgresql-9.4 features: the jsonb and its indexing seem very attractive and so does the scalikejdbc-async.

Is there a way to access JSONB values using scalikejdbc-async, and if there is not, how hard would it be to add ?

Thank you.